# Issue with CoordinatorLayout and FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout

On [picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BJyg.png) it looks fine but on [picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idmlw.png), because FAB has `app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerview_list"` attribute, it looks not fine. Is there a way to anchor FAB to the bottom side without adding custom bottom nav bar? I just want this button to stay on position permanently even if the RecyclerView changes it's height.

Here's the XML file:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="fragments.DailyListFragment">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:title="@string/sample"
        app:contentScrim="@color/accent_color1">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:progressTint="#BA0E0E" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_new_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerview_list"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="false"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview_layout_list">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: If you want it to be always at the bottom, why did you anchor it to the recyclerview?
Removing the anchor should work. Please add more details if it is required for any use-case.

Comment: Replace `app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerview_list" app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"` with `android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerview_list" 
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
```

with

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
```